# does using async before created method breaks the life cycle of vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, async-await, promise

I've read that I can add `async` before `created` method in Vue js
but doesn't that break the vue life cycle because by using async it's converted into asynchronous action and being send to the queue in the background and by that it can execute the later method like `mounted` before `created` method finishes it's job

Comment: Vue does not use the return value from any life-cycle hook so, _no_ it does not break anything

Comment: but by using `async` it's converted into asynchronous action  so it will be executed in the background right?

Comment: By using `async` you are allowed to use `await` within it and it implicitly returns a promise. That's the only difference.

Comment: `The async and await keywords enable asynchronous, promise-based behavior to be written in a cleaner style, ` this is taken from MDN

Comment: So it's asynchronous action, right?

Comment: Like I said, Vue discards any returned value (promise or otherwise) so it really doesn't matter what your `created()` hook does. The only thing to keep in mind is that any async code won't halt or delay the lifecycle. For example, you can't delay the `mounted()` hook with any async code used within `created()`

Comment: @Bergi great that's clear but just to clear everything code after might run out of order  if it doesn't depend on the result coming from the await but other wise it has to run in order right?

Answer (score 1):

> By using `async` it's converted into asynchronous action and being send to the queue in the background

Nope. It does not run in the background. It's not even deferred to "later", the function body starts executing immediately. The only difference that it can `await` something, at which point the `async function` returns a promise for its eventual result, after the "something" has finished. But Vue ignores that returned promise (like any return value).

So yes, code *after* the `await` might run "out of order", after another hook like `mounted` was called, but it'll still run in the foreground at that point. In other words, if `mounted` relies on some stuff from `created`, that will need to be done synchronously. You can still do that in the first part of an `async` function though.

This is not any different from creating a promise chain in a `created` method that is defined without `async`.

Comment: _"at which point the async function returns a promise"_ Very minor nitpick but async functions always return a promise. It might resolve immediately if there's no actual async code but it's still a promise and thus, still queued as a microtask

Comment: @Phil Yes, it also returns a promise when encountering `return` or other completion - the "at which point" was meant temporal, not conditional.

Comment: @Bergi the part that get executed in the microtask is the return value if not resolved promise am I right?

Comment: @OmarAbdelaziz Not sure what you mean, the return value is not executed. The parts of the async function that get executed in microtasks (after the respective `await`ed promise settles) are those after the first encountered `await` keyword. Which might even be none - in `async example() { console.log('right'); } example(); console.log('now');` no microtasks are involved.